# way to connect mysql which executes only once inside the for loop in bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a script which will execute Insert Query n times - for that i have used FOR loop , but the problem is the command which connects to remote mysql also executes n times. Here is the script for the better idea for my problem.

```
#!/bin/bash -X
#fields:  id|alias|booking_time|contact_no|deleted|grace|number_in_queue|pax|seated_time|status|walk_in_time|queue_id|user_id 

echo "Bash version ${BASH_VERSION}..."

for i in {1..5..1}
do
        _alias="Name$i"
        _contact_no=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '1-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1)
        _deleted="FALSE"
        _number_in_queue=$i
        _pax=$(( $RANDOM % 10 + 20 ))
        _status="waiting"
        _queue_id=424
        _user_id=550

        mysql -u root -p restbucks << EOF  #Want this to execute only One time
        INSERT INTO queue_item  VALUES ('','$_alias',now(),'$_contact_no','$_deleted',NULL,'$_number_in_queue','$_pax',now(),'$_status',now(),'$_queue_id','$_user_id');

EOF

done
```

Everytime i try to run the script , it will ask me for the password. What i want is that only once the connection made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the mysql connect before the for loop.

```
mysql -u root -p restbucks << EOF  #this execute only One time
for i in {1..5..1}
do
.....
done
EOF
```

Also it is recommended that you can write your queries into a file and then finally execute the file using single connection.

You can refer [bulk-mysql-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784332/how-to-create-a-bulk-mysql-upload-script-in-linux)

Comment: Why cant you write all the queries in a file in the loop and try exeute the file in one connection?

Comment: i don't know how to do that! i am new to this ! can u provide me with some guidance/links/tutorials etc ..!!

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is placed inside the for loop. Every time the control passes to the loop it gets executed. You don't need to connect to your server once you are connected. Try placing the statement before the FOR statement.